# How to remove time from iTextsharp PDF when i made it by getting the data from Datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime, itext

I am making a program windows application by C# and MySQL, which uses itextsharp in the reports, but when I run the report the date field contain time also same as in the picture below, in the database the field is Date only, and I make the formats of datetimepicker and datagridview as "short" ... How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an iTextsharp problem. If you want to format precisely the date you may use:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
string dateString = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

There are other options but you see the pattern.

Comment: It would be better to escape `/` character as `'/'` or supply an `IFormatProvider` that has `/` as a `DateSeparator`. Result _might_ be different if you don't do.